# Google Cloud Endpoints client library NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We have a Google Cloud Endpoints backend written in java. We generate the client library to use in other Java applications with the command

> gradlew endpointsClientLibs

Is it possible to generate a NodeJS client library from the same Java backend. We winsh to write some of out applications in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. We (the Endpoints team) are aware that users would like more client language options.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google's Discovery API to generate a client library which is based on the open API spec file in Python for my cloud endpoints api. I assume the same can be done for node.js.

Google's node.js Client Library - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis
Google's Discovery API - https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using